# In Photoshop can i resize an object without the corner and point markers getting in the way?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I resize an object to something fairly small and I want to keep a zoomed-out view to get a feel for how big I want it, sometimes the little corner and pivot point shapes get in the way of the object.

Can I temporarily disable these markers while resizing?

Answer (score 1):

With the transform handles visible...

Choose `View > Extras` from the menu to **uncheck it**. The handles should disappear, but you are **still** in transform mode. So, dragging, etc will still alter the layer, you just won't see any handles.

[image]

Recheck the `Extras` item to see handles again.

You can also use the shortcut -- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> -- to toggle the Extras item.
<sub>(Some operating systems see the shortcut as "hide the app" so you have to tell the OS to keep shortcuts localized.)</sub>

Comment: you are Photoshop wizard